# Unable to get the LTPA token using Rest assured

Tags: rest-assured, ltpa

I am new to rest assured, I want to perform some get and post for test data generation using rest assured. But I am unable to get the LTPA token and pass them to post. This works with postman but I want to do it through java. Any help

```
final String uri = "https://XXXX/Rest/XXXXX?user=XXXXX&pass=XXXX";
    final Response response = RestAssured.given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().accept(ContentType.JSON).get(uri);
    System.out.println(response.prettyPrint());
    Map<String, String> allCookies = response.cookies();
    System.out.println(allCookies);
```

Output 
{JSESSIONID=XXXXXXX:-1}

but i do not see the LTPA2 token

Answer (score 0):

Your LTPA2 token must be in Response headers.

You can get the response headers by

```
response.headers ();
```

In case if LTPA token is also not available in headers then share the screenshot of postman so I can help you out.

Comment: Thanks Wasiq, I see the cookie with ltpa token in the request headers in post man.

Comment: If my answer was helpful then you can mark it as answered.